# VBA does not save changes to Outlook Template that show up with .Display

Tags: excel, vba, templates, outlook

I am working on generating OFT files that will be e-mailed to customers who will then fill the To: and Subject: in and send them as e-mails to their clients.

My data comes from an Excel Workbook with one sheet containing static data (Books) and another information pasted in by the user (Pins).  I've got a basic template that has placeholder text which gets replaced by the data in the aforementioned Excel sheets.

One important part of this is that I need the changed template to get saved to it's own file, so it can be stored for reference later.  Originally I had the code below setup to open the template and call .SaveAs myFilename, olTemplate but that just made a broken 3KB file.  You will notice I am copying the template to the actual destination file and operating on that instead.

My problem is that if I have the template item call .Display, everything is perfect.  I see my image in the right place and all of the text is properly replaced.  If I call .Save it saves out a copy of the original OFT template with no changes present.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?  I've been searching here and google for hours trying to find some indication of what I'm missing.  I'm trying to automate this thing as much as possible.  Resaving the new OFT with Outlook's UI is a real time sink for a coworker and I'd like to eliminate that if possible.  They're going to be generating dozens of these OFTs every day, so the work seems worth it in my opinion.

**UPDATE**
I have managed to get this to work but the solution feels like a half-answer.  The code below has been updated with changes that properly save the OFT.

Here is my sub:

```
Sub OutlookTemplate(ByVal pins As Range, ByVal book As Range, ByVal ImageLocation As String)

    Dim myolapp As Object
    Dim myItem As Object

    Set myolapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    'myolapp.Session.Logon

    For Each p In pins.Cells
        If Not IsEmpty(p.Value) Then
            Dim myFilename As String
            myFilename = "c:\temp\" & Worksheets("PINS").Range("A2") & "-" & p.Value & ".oft"
            FileCopy "c:\template.oft", myFilename

            Set myItem = myolapp.CreateItemFromTemplate(myFilename)
            myItem.Save <- Added immediate save after creation of myItem

            myItem.Attachments.Add ImageLocation, olByValue, 0
            myItem.HTMLBody = Replace(myItem.HTMLBody, "THEIMAGE", "<img src='cid:" & book.Cells(2).Value & "'" & "width='154'>")
            myItem.HTMLBody = Replace(myItem.HTMLBody, "PINHERE", p.Value)
            myItem.HTMLBody = Replace(myItem.HTMLBody, "THETITLE", book.Cells(1).Value)
            myItem.HTMLBody = Replace(myItem.HTMLBody, "THESUBTITLE", book.Cells(3).Value)
            myItem.HTMLBody = Replace(myItem.HTMLBody, "THEAUTHORS", book.Cells(4).Value)
            myItem.HTMLBody = Replace(myItem.HTMLBody, "THEDESCRIPTION", book.Cells(5).Value)

            ' Leaving the next line off results in a broken image
            ' when .SaveAs is called
            myItem.Display

            ' This saves all of the changes out to the file properly
            ' in combination with .Display
            ' Note: if I call myItem.SaveAs myFilename, olTemplate 
            ' I get the 3KB broken OFT.  Omitting ,olTemplate works
            myItem.SaveAs myFilename



        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That's frustrating. I've never tried this before, but a quick test of CreateItemFromTemplate using a template in its default location works fine. The changes are saved to the drafts folder. Of course I'm doing it inside the open application, not calling a new one. In the back of my mind there's something about displaying the application first and the ActiveInspector window, but can't see why that would matter here.

Why are you copying the template elsewhere, instead of using default Outlook location?

Do you have any simplified version of this functionality that works? If not, maybe simplify.

Comment: I copied the template to a new file because I was getting a broken OFT if I tried to use SaveAs with a different file name (also provided olTemplate to SaveAs).  My starting template is about 56KB and the file I was getting from SaveAs was 3KB and threw an error when Outlook tried to open it.  I hate to admit this but since I do not work with Outlook on a regular basis, I don't even know where you're suggesting I put the files.  I've tried c:\users\zach\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook and had the same result.  I was using c:\ and c:\temp at the start because it was less to type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Save** method doesn't propagate changes to the .oft file. It saves the Microsoft Outlook item to the current folder or, if this is a new item, to the Outlook default folder for the item type.

Try to open the existing .oft file without copying it anywhere. Then do the required changes and call the [SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868727.aspx) method to save it as a template wherever you need.

Comment: Using SaveAs on the original template was the first thing I tried.  It looked like this `myItem.SaveAs myFilename, olTemplate`.  There was no file copying or anything like that.  What ended up with was a 3KB file that outlook could not open.  I will move the starting template to c:\temp and try SaveAs again but without providing any additional path information.

Comment: Try to choose another drive or folder. The C: drive requires admin privileges for writing on recent Windows OS.

Comment: Are you able to save a message as a template to the specified folder? Do you see a broken 3KB then?

Comment: If I open outlook I can save messages to c:\temp without a problem.  If I call .Display on myItem, I can use the Outlook UI to save the new template to that folder and my changes are present.  I've just moved the template to c:\temp from c:\ and updated my VBA to use SaveAs with a new file name and olTemplate as the variant.  Still a 3KB file.

Comment: Here are just the lines that changed  `myFilename = "c:\temp\" & Worksheets("PINS").Range("A2") & "-" & p.Value & ".oft"
Set myItem = myolapp.CreateItemFromTemplate("c:\temp\template.oft")
myItem.SaveAs myFilename, olTemplate`

Comment: So I have managed to get this to work but I don't feel like it is really an "answer".  So I'm still looking for someone to give me a less kludgy option or at least tell me why this works.  I will update my original question for proper formatting.

Comment: Eugene, if no one else can come up with an answer, I'm going to accept this one.  After reading it a couple times it prompted me to try to issue a save before I did my replace calls and then try SaveAs at the end.